# Why am I getting no attribute '__getitem__' error for dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, optparse

Why am I getting no attribute `__getitem__` error for dictionary:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./thumbnail.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "./thumbnail.py", line 19, in main
    options['input_pattern']
AttributeError: Values instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, glob
from PIL import Image
from optparse import OptionParser

def batch_convert(src_dir, input_pattern, output_ext = None, dest_dir = None):
    return 0

def main():
    print sys.argv
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-s", "--source-dir", dest="src_dir", help="Source directory to fetch images")
    parser.add_option("-d", "--dest-dir", dest="dest_dir", help="Destination directory to writen processed images")
    parser.add_option("-i", "--input-pattern", dest="input_pattern", help="Look for files that match some pattern. E.g. *.png or pic*cool*")
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output-format", dest="output_ext", help="Output format to save all images. If empty, original format of images is preserved")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    print options
    options['input_pattern']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`options` is not a dict:

```
print options.input_pattern
```

Answer (score 7):

If you must have a dict, use

```
options.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

As another user said, options is not a dictionary. I made this mistake myself. 
If I have an option 
`--file FILE`

Then I can call

`option.file`

which returns FILE. It's that easy!